MySQL workbench error de conexión
Estoy aprendiendo SQL y Bases de Datos, al intentar abrir "Local instante 3306" MySQL Workbench me sale lo siguiente:
Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (9.0.1).
A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0.
Please note: there may be some incompatibilities with version 8.4.
For MySQL Server older than 5.6, please use MySQL Workbench version 6.3.
Ha sido error mío al instalarlo? Tengo que instalar una versión anterior?

Cuando abro Local instante 3306 , me aparece: Warning -not supported.

Hola, ten en cuenta que MySQL Workbench no es otra cosa que un cliente o interfaz gráfica para conectarse a la base de datos, no es la base de datos en sí misma. El mensaje de error es claro. La versión de MySQL que tienes en tu sistema es la 8.4 y la versión de Workbench instalada no está actualizada para esa versión. Puedes hacer dos cosas: 1. Verificar que haya una versión de Workbench compatible con 8.4 (recomendado) 2. O bien instalar la versión 8.0 de MySQL.

Mil gracias @A.Cedano , parece ser que MySQL Workbench todavía no tiene una versión compatible con MySQL 8.4 , tendré que hacer lo segundo o buscar otra interfaz gráfica. Muchísimas gracias.

Realmente, MySQL Workbench debería estar capacitado para trabajar con la versión 8.4. Pero parece que hay un error en el código interno que reconoce las versión. Ver este pull request el cual supongo que deberá ser aprobado para parchear el error. De todos modos, existen interfaces más ligeras como DBeaver que además sirven para varios SGBD.

Recuerda que también puedes interactuar con la base de datos desde la consola. Uno se acostumbra demasiado a las interfaces gráficas, pero a veces, sobre todo para consultas, verificaciones, etc, puedes hacerlo desde la consola directamente, siendo además más rápido.
